# Asynchrounous programming in Julia

Tags: string, algorithm, asynchronous, concurrency, julia

I have an Aho-Corasick algorithm that I implemented in Julia. I would like to look at 1 Million words from a file and apply my Aho function to them to see if a word appears in the file. How can I do this asynchronously in Julia? My initial idea is to spawn multiple instances of my Aho function and each one looks at a certain portion of the file. As soon as one of them returns true, I exit. I'm not too familiar with Julia and so I wanted to know what features of the language I should be looking at.

Comment: you can have a look at [multi-threading in Julia](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/multi-threading/)

Comment: As a side note - are you planning on sharing the code on GitHub or alike?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will do a threaded search for a word in a dictionary, one thread per word. You would need to read your 1000000 word file into memory to do it this way.

```
function foreachword(wordfile::String, condition::Function)
    words = split(read(wordfile, String), r"\s+")
    continuecondition = Threads.Atomic{Bool}(true)
    @Threads.threads for word in words
        if continuecondition[] && condition(word)
            println("word found")
            continuecondition[] = false  # loop will run on all, but not do the potentially expensive call any more
        end
    end
end

iscalliope(w) = w == "calliope"

foreachword("unixdict.txt", iscalliope)
```

You could also (see comment below) do the split on segments of the file (with allowance for a segment splitting a word in two):

```
function foreachchunk(wordfile::String, condition::Function, maxwordlength=30)
    fsize = stat(wordfile).size
    chunksize = fsize ÷ Threads.nthreads()
    text = read(wordfile, String)
    continuecondition = Threads.Atomic{Bool}(true)
    @Threads.threads for start in 1:chunksize:fsize-chunksize
        segment = @view text[start : min(fsize, start + chunksize + maxwordlength)]
        words = split(segment, r"\s+")
        for word in words
            continuecondition[] || break
            if condition(word)
                println("word found")
                continuecondition[] = false
            end
        end
    end
end

foreachchunk("unixdict.txt", iscalliope)
```

Comment: I do not like this design - since word splitting occurs in a single thread. You should load file into memory and than immediately spread its bytes among threads. each thread than should look for words

Comment: I added such a version.

Comment: @Bill can you explain the purpose of `iscalliope`?

Comment: iscalliope() was a test function for the purpose of running the example (in the example, iscalliope(w) returns true when  w == "calliope").  I suppose that you would use your own function instead, assuming that it is run on each word of the file, as the split() creates that kind of list. If your function takes larger amounts of text than just one word, you would need to rewrite the example to not split on individual words.